# How do I disable swipe animation when user directly tap on tab bar item?

Tags: swift, gesture, uipangesturerecognizer

In my project, I enable a coacopods called 'SwipeableTabBarController'. These allow my tab bar view controller detect pan gestures and switch between tabs. And I also write some code to detect swipe gesture, which allows users to hide the tab bar. 
Problem: My app will have a slide animation even when the user directly tap on the bar item. Any way to solve this? I appreciated any help!

Tried to disable swipe and pan gestures when a tap is detected. But the pan gestures are not in my gesture array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `isSwipeEnabled = false` to disable the swipe feature. By default it is set to true in `SwipeableTabBarController`

**UPDATE:**

Since you are looking for a solution without the animation that `SwipeableTabBarController` library provides, but still want the swipe feature. Here is how you can do this with the default `UITabBarController`.

**Step 1:**
Create a default `UITabBarController` and 2 View Controllers, lets call them `ViewController_1` & `ViewController_2`

**Step 2:**
Create a class for each `ViewController` and in the `ViewDidLoad()` method of both `ViewController_1` & `ViewController_2` add these lines.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let swipeRight = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(swiped))
    swipeRight.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.right
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeRight)

    let swipeLeft = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(swiped))
    swipeLeft.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizer.Direction.left
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(swipeLeft)

}
```

And then add this function for every time a swipe is detected in both the classes.

```
@objc  func swiped(_ gesture: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    if gesture.direction == .left {
        if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! < 2
        {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex += 1
        }
    } else if gesture.direction == .right {
        if (self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex)! > 0 {
            self.tabBarController?.selectedIndex -= 1
        }
    }
}
```

This will give you the ability to swipe and navigate to different ViewControllers and also navigate using the `Tabbar` buttons.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks! It seems not work for my code... I re-start a new project and put 3 tab items. Then I put SwipeableTabBarController = false inside viewDidLoad(). But it seems as long as I inherit from SwipeableTabBarController. I still got the animation........

Comment: Ok let me try to reproduce this and see if i can find a solution. If i do i will update my answer.

Comment: Just come up with a solution...Not sure if whether it's a good way but it do the job..I use beginAppearanceTransition(false animated: false) inside tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem).. Then re-enable in touchesEnded()..

Comment: Yes that seems to do the job. But why don't you use the default `UITabBarController` ??? Why are you using `SwipeableTabBarController` ?? Are you using it for the swipe feature ???

Comment: Yes.. I am just aiming for the swipe feature. And  `SwipeableTabBarController` inherit from  `UITabBarController`.. So I am assuming there is no difference? ahhhh I am actually quite new to swift though.....

Comment: If you go with `SwipeableTabBarController` then you will have to sacrifice on having an animation when you click on the Tabbar item. Instead why don't you build a swipe feature for the default `UITabBarController` I will update my answer with some basic code. Then you can customize it accordingly. Is that Ok ?

Comment: I have updated my answer. This should help you achieve what your trying without using `SwipeableTabBarController`. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the property of your POD `isSwipeEnabled = false` on your tap action

It will disable scroll animation when you tap on tabbar items.